# Why can I put classes and not functions in a .h file without getting the multiple definitions error?

Tags: c++

I recently had a problem where I was writing a library with lots of function definitions in the .h files and as the library got more interdependent I started running into lots of multiple definitions of functions errors so in order to reduce refactoring I declared all my functions as inline, but I'm wondering why I didn't have to change anything for the classes defined in the same .h files? Shouldn't the classes also be getting duplicated?

Comment: Because you aren't writing class *definitions*, you are writing class *declarations*.

Comment: `I was writing a library with lots of function definitions in the .h files` That's the problem right there. Headers should contain *declarations*, not *definitions*. `in order to reduce refactoring I declared all my functions as inline` That's not the right way to "*fix*" it. Leave the function *declarations* in the headers, move the *implementation* to cpp files.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, I guess functions defined inside of classes are defined as inline by default so that explains why I don't need to modify them.

Comment: @EJP - no; `class X { void f(); };` is a class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare variables, functions and classes in a header, and include that header into multiple translation units, and have no problems. But what you've been doing is *defining* functions, which is different.

Classes are special in that you may define them in multiple translation units, *as long as the contents of each copy are precisely identical* — this special rule is important because otherwise your classes wouldn't be very useful; a class that has only been *declared* can't be immediately used for very much, whereas a function that has only been declared can be immediately used for pretty much anything.

That's just a consequence of the different nature of the two kinds of things.

```
// Declarations
extern int x;  // variable
void foo();    // function
class T;       // class

// Definitions
int x;         // variable
void foo() {}  // function
class T {};    // class
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why a class that has only been declared can't be used for very much?

Comment: @zimzam: A class that's only been declared (colloquially we call this a "forward declaration") can only be used in very limited ways; basically anything that doesn't need to know the class's "size", or what members are within it. So for a class `T` you could only really do anything with a `T*` or a `T&` (or use it as a template parameter in _some_ cases). As soon as you want to instantiate a `T`, or copy one (including return by value, which includes declaring a function that returns by value!), or access any of its members, you need the full definition. None of that is true for function calls

Comment: okay that makes sense now that I've reread it, but if it's so easy to check that a definition of a class is identical, why not just do the same thing with function definitions? Why bother reporting a compile time error if both function definitions are identical? Wouldn't it make more sense for two identical function definitions to result in a warning instead?

Comment: @zimzam: C heritage. It could be done and, in fact, if you mark your function `inline` (or it's a function template specialisation) that's exactly what happens. But normal functions generally abide by old C rules for compatibility. There are actually some technical and "philosophical" reasons why it makes sense this way anyway, but that's out of the scope of this comment section :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put functions also in `.h` files, but also function definitions only; not declarations, **unless** they are template functions. So basically it's the same rules with classes, except that with classes, if you do them the quick-and-dirty way, you put everything inside the class itself and you combine definitions with declarations, which is not really good practice.

So:

This goes to an .h file:

```
int DoSomething(double x, double y);
```

And this goes to a .cpp file

```
int DoSomething(double x, double y)
{        
    return static_cast<int>(x+y);
}
```

While this (if you care about templates, otherwise just ignore this), **can only** go to an .h file:

```
template <typename T>
int DoSomething(T x, T y)
{        
    return static_cast<int>(x+y);
}
```

This whole thing is not for fun. There's a very good reason for it. The reason is that `.h` files represent an [*API*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), while `.cpp` files represent an *implementation*. Ideally, an *API* is something you plan ahead and never changes. On the other hand, an implementation can be updated to fix bugs, for example.

Also *cpp* files can be compiled to a dynamic link library (dll) or shared library, which can be then updated without modifying the API. So you can use the same API in your program by including some `.h` file, and *link it* to a different implementations, if you like.

And if you ask: Why templates can only be in `.h` files, it's because compiled stuff must be with a predefined type. You can't compile something without knowing what type it is.

The story can go for pages... but I think this suffices to explain the basics (I hope).

Comment: I didn't bother mentioning templates at all, for this level of explanation, though if you're to do so it may be worth disclaiming that "this can only go to an .h file" is not true; it's just that that is usually the only way to make the function template _useful_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you mean with making it useful? How would it work otherwise? Please explain.

Comment: You can define your function templates in `.cpp` files just fine. But if you want to use the resulting specialisations in another translation unit you're stuck. That's why we conventionally bung them into headers (or files included into headers) instead, because we usually want to be able to use our templates throughout the program... or, at least, in more than one place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I remember never being able to get this to work. Well, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: [This page](http://warp.povusers.org/programming/export_templates.html) may or may not be interesting; I didn't read it in detail but the topic is relevant.